# Получение нескольких значений в одной строке

Tags: python, словари

Допустим есть такой код, как сделать чтобы данные от пользователя получать с одной строки.
Например "Молоко 80"

```
my_basket = {}
ware_1 = input("Продукт - ")
my_basket[ware_1] = int(input("Цена - "))
total_cost = sum(my_basket.values())
print("Total cost -", total_cost)
```

Comment: `user_input = input('Продукт и цена через пробел: ').split(); ware = user_input[0]; my_basket[ware] = int(user_input[1])`

Answer (score 0):

python v2:

```
my_basket={'milk': 100}

ware, price = raw_input().split()
my_basket[ware] = int(price)

search_ware = raw_input()
if search_ware in my_basket:
    print('Ware: {0}'.format(my_basket[search_ware]))
```

python v3:

```
my_basket={'milk': 100}

ware, price = input().split()
my_basket[ware] = int(price)

search_ware = input()
if search_ware in my_basket:
    print(f'Ware: {my_basket[search_ware]}')
```